# Invalid UTF-8 string

Tags: c, gtk

I trying to swap the window title with the label inside the window on 
keypress.

Below is my code :

```
#include<gtk/gtk.h>
static gboolean key_press_event(GtkWidget*,GdkEvent*,gpointer);

   int main(int argv, char* argc[])
    {
      GtkWidget *window,*label;
      gtk_init(&argv,&argc);
      window=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
      gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),"Sajith");
      gtk_widget_set_size_request(window,300,100);
      label=gtk_label_new("Sam");
      gtk_label_set_selectable(GTK_LABEL(label),TRUE);
      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),label);
      g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window),"key_press_event",
                       G_CALLBACK(key_press_event),label);
      gtk_widget_show_all(window);
      gtk_main();
    }
    static gboolean key_press_event(GtkWidget* window, GdkEvent* event, gpointer label)
    {
      GtkWidget* newlabel;
      newlabel=GTK_LABEL(label);
      const gchar* wtitle=gtk_window_get_title(GTK_WINDOW(window));
      gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),gtk_label_get_text(GTK_LABEL(newlabel)));
      gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(newlabel),wtitle);

      /* I am not sure if I could pass wtitle here*/
      return FALSE;
    }
```

On execution the window title is successfully swapped but the label is not.
Also, I get the following warning at the terminal.

```
(2p1:12005): Pango-WARNING **: Invalid UTF-8 string passed to pango_layout_set_text()
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gtk_window_get_title()` returns a static buffer owned by the window. This buffer will have been changed after the `gtk_window_set_title()` call.

To achieve what you want, you should, in your callback function, create a copy of the string. You can use `strdup()`, but it may not be available on all platforms. Since you are using GTK+ which depends on GLib, you can use `g_strdup()`. Example:

```
gchar* wtitle = g_strdup(gtk_window_get_title(GTK_WINDOW(window)));
```

Remember to free it before the callback function returns with `g_free(wtitle)`.

As for the return value, since the callback function returns `gboolean`, you cannot return `wtitle`. For your case, I don't see any difference between returning `TRUE` or `FALSE`, as there aren't any default handlers anyway. If, instead of a label, you are using something like a GtkEntry, then you would return `TRUE` if you don't want the text in the entry to be replaced by your input key.